# scrollify footer bottom positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-scrollify

It's been a while i've been trying to solve this out myself. I am using [scrollify jquery](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify). I have total of FIVE sections and scrollify is working totally fine. 
I want the footer to be shown in the last section named "five" but it's out of the section.

Here goes my code:

```
<section class="panel five" data-section-name="five">
   <div class="contactus bottom-10">
      <!-- IT WAS JUST A CONTACT US FORM, I removed it so the code looks easy and small -->
   </div>
   <!-- end contact us -->

   <div id="footer-wrapper">
      <footer>
         <!-- FOOTER CODES --> 
      </footer>
   </div> <!--end footer wrapper -->
</section>
```

CSS

```
#footer-wrapper {
   width:100%;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   height: 50px;
}
```

Part of the jquery

```
$(function () {
   $(".panel").css({
      "height": $(window).height()
   });

   $.scrollify({
      section: ".panel" //This is the part to detect section ?
   });

   $(".scroll").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.scrollify("move", $(this).attr("href"));
   });
});
```

So basically i want to fall the footer-wrapper into the bottom of the page withing the section five. but what happens to be is it goes beyond the section.
 removing absolute will bring the footer upwards and will create a gaping in the bottom. I cannot give margin-top because in different screens, its gonna cause a problem.

I have used this plugin named scrollify - http://codepen.io/gam3ov3r/pen/zrdqy

Comment: you should try with position:relative coz you put one div as part of scrolling div so you should try with that else you need to clarify what you are exactly mean by missed-out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, have you tried `fixed`instead of `absolute` ?

```
#footer-wrapper {
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;/* <== */
 bottom:0;
 height: 50px;

 z-index:999;/* could be useful... */
}
```

**EDIT** 
In addition, you have to used JS/JQuery to hide/show it. `absolute` and `fixed` works for the whole html page. Therefore you have to detect when Section 5 is displayed or not, and show()/hide() #footer-wrapper conssequently.

```
var isSection5_displayed = /* ... check it here ... */;
if(isSection5_displayed) $("#footer-wrapper").show()
else $("#footer-wrapper").hide();
```

Therefore, the deal is to detect "Section 5 has shown"/"Section has passed hidden". Or better "A section has taken the place, Section #X", if (X==5), if(X!=5)...".

Comment: Yeah i did tried fixed, it stays in the bottom but footer is displayed in every section.

Comment: Thanks,i edited my question aswell. you understood well what i was trying to say. Will try to figure out with jquery you had just mentioned.

Comment: The real deal, to me, is to detect "Section 5 has shown"/"Section has passed hidden". Or better: "A section has taken the place, Section #X", "if (X==5) show footer, if(X!=5) hide footer". That deserves a new question 'how to detect Section changes in the plugin'. SY.

Comment: Can you please review the question again. I've added the jquery part which had section in it. I don't know any of jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Make #footer-wrapper absolute, but **in a relative div**. This relative div could , it should be. Thus, #footer-w... is absolute, relatively to section, not body, and you'll see footer only in section 5.

It is only CSS.

CSS:

```
section5 {
position:relative
}

#footer-wrapper {
   /* what you already did */
}
```

Reading: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Both of your answer worked. It was actually my mistake, i did not had a good indention of wrapper ids. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome:) enjoy coding